# How to get all URLs in a Symfony 4 project to contain the _locale

Tags: twig, symfony4

Am trying to create a language switcher for a Symfony 4 project (with Twig). Basically when clicking a link, the website's language will change.

Configuration I have is this:

`config\packages\translation.yaml`

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
```

This is the important lines I got in

`config\packages\services.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    # This parameter defines the codes of the locales (languages) enabled in the application
    app_locales: en|fr
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Json;

// Class name really should match Controller name
class ControllerBase extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}", name="app_landing", defaults={"_locale" = "en"}, requirements={"_locale" = "en|fr"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->getLocale();
        return $this->render('landing/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

The actual language switcher is just two list elements contained in the template file. They look like this:

`<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a></li>`

`<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">French</a></li>`

This works fine.

Problem arises when clicking another link on the website. It doesn't contain the _locale and the site defaults back to `en`.

I really would like the _locale to be added to each link automatically (including the index path "/").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of experimenting, I found the answer.

I tried to do the same thing in two different ways. In my case it was best to simply use the code in the template file and omit the {_locale} parameter in the controller.

Like that all works fine.